# Getting the image path from the camera plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

as I think , this will output the data of the image

```
let cameraOptions = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
    }
```

but this will will output the path of the image

```
let cameraOptions = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL 
    }
```

I want to output both - as long as I’ll upload the image data and need the path also

please mention this part in your answer if some changes required in it

```
this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((data) => {
       this.imgDate = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
     });
```

Comment: you can only get one, why do you need both?

Comment: @jcesarmobile , when the user select the image - he should see the photo he selected <img [src]="imageHeSelected"> , and then I upload it to the server

Comment: as long as noway to achieve that - I'll have to upload the image to the server then use the download link <img [src]="downloadImageLink"> , thanks anyway

Comment: if you get the url, you can use the url as the image src and it will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve showing picture without URL. No need to upload first

```
let cameraOptions = {
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
}
this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((data) => {
    this.imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
    this.sendToServer(this.imgData);//base64 server sending
});
<img [src]="imgData">
```

Comment: <img [src]="imgData"> , this.imgData is not a path - this will not work

Comment: @AboMohsen, img.src could be URL or Base64, see example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/6744399